# The "to_csv' method does not prompt the download window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to download my dataset. I am using Python 3 on Google Colab.

Unfortunately, the code works, but no download window appears that would prompt me to download my dataframe, that I converted using the "to_csv" method of Pandas library.

Here is my code

```
download = pd.DataFrame()
download.to_csv('techInd.csv', index=False)
```

I even tried providing the entire path to download the file but no avail:

```
download = pd.DataFrame()
download.to_csv('C:\Users\dell pc\Desktop\Fyyp\data_banks\techInd.csv', index=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think a window should appear? What line of your code tries to bring up a window?

Comment: I assume it does so automatically? How else am I supposed to know that the required file has been downloaded? I have checked my directory and the "Downloads" tab in my browser (Chrome) to check

Comment: What’s your working directory? It’s probably writing to some colab network location. It won’t automatically download for you. See https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Comment: What you mean by working directory? I checked my drive where I have all my ipynb colab files saved. I did not find any csv file over there.

Comment: What’s the output of os.listcwd()? Also os.listdir(‘.’) should contain your csvs name

Answer (score 0):

Using the file browser on the left hand side, right click and select download to save any file.

Here's a complete example:
[image]